# Null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint in Django 1.9

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have exhausted all avenues in trying to put together a solution for this, but my current knowledge of Python and Django can only get me so far.

I'm creating a basic ticketing system and CreateView used to work until I created a Profile model and then separated the Ticket model into its own app.  There were already a couple of tickets created when I refactored my code which is why I know ListView works, DeleteView works as well as DetailView.  CreateView works until I hit the save button.

My views and models are below; I hope someone can please help me sort this out.

Ticket Model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
....
from qcapp.models import Profile


class Ticket(models.Model):
    # Relations
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="tickets", verbose_name="user")
    # Attributes
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name="Title", help_text="Enter a Ticket Title")
    color = models.CharField(max_length=7,
                             default="#ffffff",
                             validators=[RegexValidator("(^#[0-9a-fA-F]{3}$)|(^#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}$)")],
                             verbose_name="Color",
                             help_text="Enter the hex color code, like #ccc or #cccccc")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Created Date')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='created_by_user')
    # Attributes
    # Object Manager
    objects = managers.ProjectManager()

    # Meta and String
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Ticket"
        verbose_name_plural = "Tickets"
        ordering = ("user", "title")
        unique_together = ("user", "title")

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.user, self.title)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('ticket_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Ticket View (CreateView Only)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
...
from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
...
from .models import Ticket


...

class TicketCreate(CreateView):
    model = Ticket
    template_name = "tickets/ticket_form.html"
    fields = ['title', 'description']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super(TicketCreate, self).form_valid(form)

...
```

Profile Model(Imported Into Ticket Model)

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from . import managers


class Profile(models.Model):
    # Relations
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile", verbose_name="user")
    # Attributes
    interaction = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="interaction")
    # Attributes
    # Object Manager
    objects = managers.ProfileManager()

    # Custom Properties
    @property
    def username(self):
        return self.user.username

    # Methods

    # Meta and String
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Profile"
        verbose_name_plural = "Profiles"
        ordering = ("user",)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_profile_for_new_user(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = Profile(user=instance)
        profile.save()
```

Comment: What are you having a problem saving? `Ticket` or `Profile` or both? I'm going to assume `Ticket`. If that's the case, you are assigning the `created_by` field but you're not assigning `user`.

Comment: Profile works good...just added it to this ticket just incase it was relevant in the solution.  Can you please provide an example of assigning the user to the ticket?  Thank you.

Comment: Well in `form_valid()` of your `TicketCreate` you already do: `form.instance.created_by = self.request.user` so I'm thinking you need to do this: `form.instance.user = self.request.user`

Comment: I changed the form.instance to what you suggested and got the error `Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: charles>>": "Ticket.user" must be a "Profile" instance.` I am guessing this is why I include the Profile model above.

Comment: Ah crud, sorry I missed that user was a foreign key to `Profile`. Then you're going to have to get the `Profile` of the user creating the ticket (assuming that's who `user` is supposed to be) and assign it that way.

Comment: Sounds logical, I'm researching this now but not having any luck...have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103997/discussion-between-themanatuf-and-studio-rooster).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you need to add the following to your `TicketCreate` class in the `form_valid` function:

```
form.instance.user = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
```

Let me know if that works!